# SIGABRT when saving to managed object context in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This code is supposed to save my data to core data in TestViewController.m file:

```
//Property
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;


//Methods
- (void)saveUser:(NSString *) username withEmail:(NSString *) email withName:(NSString *) name
{
    //1
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    //2
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    User *coreDataUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    coreDataUser.username = username;
    coreDataUser.email = email;
    coreDataUser.name = name;

    NSError *error;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

//In my save user method I have stuff that is done in another thread but then this is called:

// Add in any UIKit code here on main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (isUnique == YES)
        {
            [self saveUser:[emailStr lowercaseString] withEmail:emailStr withName:nameStr];
```

My code always crashes on:

```
ser *coreDataUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

It says signal SIGABRT in main.

I am following this tutorial: http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-core-data-tutorial-with-example/

And running in ios 7.

What am I missing?

I'm tracing the appDelegate.m code now but it looks like this:

```
// 1
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
    _    managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

//2
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    _managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

    return _managedObjectModel;
}

//3
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSString *test = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *test2 = test;

    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"HappyPeople.sqlite"]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

i    f (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error])
    {
        /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

Seems like the sqllite db file gets created.

The exception I am getting is this:

```
NSException *    name:@"NSInternalInconsistencyException" reason:@"+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Users' in this model."    0x0895ee20
```

Comment: Is `appDelegate.managedObjectContext` nil?

Comment: good starting point, i'll test

Comment: hmmm must be something with the creating of the context. I followed what was in the URL and they start nil, but they should be created like in the link

Comment: If it's code in the AppDelegate, it wouldn't hurt to throw that up as well ;)

Comment: Okay I will do that now

Comment: updated question with appdelegate code

Comment: Hmm. Not a lot of error I could absorb other than that you shouldn't need to retain the mangedObjectContext from TestViewController (since it's retained by the AppDelegate). Might be worth stepping through the debugger and finding which object isn't being successfully created.

Comment: yeah that's what i'm doing, line by line, seems the .sqlite file gets created correctly

Comment: it appears the database gets created, but there is no user table there, just a master table and z_metadata and z_primary

Comment: is the save entity supposed to create the tables?

Comment: add an assertion: `assert([NSThread isMainThread]);` at the beginning of your AppDelegate `managedObjectContext` method

Comment: I put an assert in the AppDelegate method and right before User *coreDataUser and both are in the main thread. I wonder if it's a framework issue?

Comment: I keep getting this error on that line:  NSException *    name:@"NSInternalInconsistencyException" reason:@"+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Users' in this model."    0x0895ee20

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old...

This is the exception I get when I change the schema of the object model and try to use a file with the old schema. The sqllite db on disk may not match your apps schema.

I have been using CoreData with a UIManagedDocument so it is a little different. There you have options to automatically migrate on the open.

Also, early on in the comments it was asked whether the ManagedObjectContext was nil. I believe that this should be checked before you call the insert. Are we sure all of the core data setup is on the main queue? It can take a little time to open. (Again with UIManagedDocument is explicitly on another thread.)